# Is there a way to extract rosbag files without using ros packages

Tags: ros, rosbag, ros-lunar, extract-images

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While ROS is useful, t's very annoying to install. I'm trying to make an extraction pipeline that is user friendly and can be used across multiple platforms and ros packages just get in the way. All I want to do is extract videos. Has anyone created a script (preferably in python or matlab), to easily extract rosbag files?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287135/is-there-a-way-to-extract-rosbag-files-without-using-ros-packages/) by [roswell anyoha](https://answers.ros.org/users/34409/roswell-anyoha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-03-30**:
I doubt it. The ROS bag format is complex and the only libraries I'm aware of that can read it are the ones provided by ROS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could see whether [swri-robotics/bag-reader-java](https://github.com/swri-robotics/bag-reader-java) has some useful parts.

I must agree with @ahendrix though: in general `bag`s are really only fully useful with ROS in the mix, but for just extracting image data you should be able to get by with the implementation I linked above. Note that this will just get you the data. Decoding it will be on you.

---

Edit: opinionated bits below, feel free to ignore.

> While ROS is useful, t's very annoying to install.

This is rather subjective, but I have a bit of a hard time agreeing with this (especially the *very* part). `ros-core` is less than 50 MB iirc (total size of pkgs) and has a relatively limited set of dependencies. The Docker images are between 290 and 390 MB, which is also rather small. A from-sources install on a regular Ubuntu or Debian desktop is also trivial (5 lines and some time).

> I'm trying to make an extraction pipeline that is user friendly and can be used across multiple platforms and ros packages just get in the way.

One accepted approach I've seen used is to delegate the ROS/platform specific parts to a hosted web service, which takes care of massaging the data into whatever format you like. Several platforms/companies have formed around this idea, such as [Bag Database](https://github.com/swri-robotics/bag-database), [Marv](https://ternaris.com/marv-robotics/) and [BotBags](https://discourse.ros.org/t/announcing-botbags-the-cloud-rosbag-storage-service/916/7). Using a REST API the format specifics can be delegated to the hosted services and clients can download whatever formats the server can transform the data into.

A disadvantage of this approach is of course that clients would have to upload their bags first.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0